# When to use BackendlessCollection vs List with Backendless.Persistence.of

Tags: java, backendless

I have seen examples of the `Backendless.Persistence.of` results stored in both  `List<E>` and `BackendlessCollection<E>`.

What is it recommended to use `BackendlessCollection` instead of `List`?

```
// https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_relations_retrieve.htm
List<Contact> result = Backendless.Persistence.of( Contact.class ).find( dataQuery ).getCurrentPage();


// https://backendless.com/feature-17-data-paging-or-how-to-efficiently-load-large-data-sets-in-a-mobile-app/
BackendlessCollection<Restaurant> restaurants = Backendless.Persistence.of(Restaurant.class).find( dataQuery );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List and BackendlessCollection are not the same. BackendlessCollection contains multiple pages (which you can get as list), so one may say that BackendlessCollection consists of Lists.

**upd:**
You receive a `BackendlessCollection` whenever you call `find()` method of the SDK. This main reason this class has to exist is that if you have, say, 1000 rows, it is not efficient to retrieve them all at once, since it would take a lot of time. So `BackendlessCollection` initially has only first 10 of them, by default. This number is called a *page size*.

In order to work with the objects, you need to retrieve them from `BackenlessCollection`. You do that with `BackendlessCollection.getCurrentPage()` method, which returns a `List` with 10 objects, by default. After that you may work with it just like with any other list of objects in Java.

Then you may want to retrieve more than just first 10 objects, so now you call `BackendlessCollection.nextPage()` method, which returns another `BackendlessCollection`, which now contains the objects from 10 to 20. Again, to work with them you need to retrieve the inner `List` with `BackendlessCollection.getCurrentPage()` method and use these next 10 objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping that you would say something like, use List<E> when you want to XXX and you use BackendlessCollection<E> when you want to do YYY. List<E> can do this but BackendlessCollection<E> cannot and BackendlessCollection<E> can do this but List<E> can not. Based on your answer, I still do not know when and why each should be used.

Comment: Added some details, hope it helps.